# Listing files and folders with TYPO3 extbase fluid?

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase

I have files array like

```
'file1.pdf',
'file2.pdf',
'file3.JPG',
'Folder1/file1.pdf',
'Folder1/Subfolder1/Subfolder-file1.txt',
'Folder2/text.txt',
'Folder2/file2.pdf'
```

For get list of files and folder I  use following fluid

```
<f:for each="{files}" as="userFile">
  <f:if condition="{userFile -> myext:explode(delimiter:'/') -> f:count()} == 1">
  <f:then>
    <a href="{userDirectory}{userFile}" target="_blank">{userFile}</a><br />
  </f:then>
  <f:else>
   <div class="folder">
    <f:for each="{userFile -> myext:explode(delimiter:'/')}" as="segment" iteration="itemIteration">
    <f:if condition="{itemIteration.isFirst}">
      <f:then>{segment}</f:then>
      <f:else><a href="{userDirectory}{userFile}" target="_blank">{segment}</a><br /></f:else>              
    </f:if>
   </f:for> 
  </div>    
 </f:else>
</f:if>
</f:for>
```

I'm using my own explode view helper

And I get only list files and folders

```
<a href="">file1.pdf</a>
<a href="">file2.pdf</a>
<a href="">file3.JPG</a>
  <div class="folder">Folder1</div>
    <a href="">file1.pdf</a>
  <div class="folder">Folder1</div>
   <a href="">Subfolder1 
     <a href="">Subfolder-file1.txt</a>

<div class="folder">Folder2</div>
  <a href="">text.txt</a>
<div class="folder">Folder2</div>
 <a href="">file2.pdf</a>
```

How I can get listing like with fluid?

```
<a href="">file1.pdf</a>
<a href="">file2.pdf</a>
<a href="">file3.JPG</a>

<div class="folder">Folder1</div>
  <a href="">file1.pdf</a>
  Subfolder-file1.txt
    <a href="">Subfolder-file1.txt</a>

<div class="folder">Folder2</div>
 <a href="">text.txt</a>
 <a href="">file2.pdf</a>
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Maybe it will be a better solution to get an prepared array from the controller, so that you can simple loop them. How to you get `{files}`?

Comment: You should check at this extension : https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/file_list/

Comment: I get files via $files = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::getAllFilesAndFoldersInPath(array(), $dirPath, '', 0, 99, '');

Comment: @D.Vasiliev Please also provide the version number of yopur TYPO3 instance in your next questions. This will help you avoid failing cause of breaking changes between versions

Answer (score 2):

In your Extbase Controller you can use the `TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\ResourceFactory` to get folders:

```
$resourceFactory = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\ResourceFactory::getInstance();
// Format [ID OF STORAGE]:[FOLDER]
$folder          = $resourceFactory->getFolderObjectFromCombinedIdentifier('1:my/directory/to/scan');
$this->view->assign('folder', $folder);
```

Now you can use folowing partial in your fluid to walk the folders:

**`Partial/FolderRecusive.html`**

```
<f:for each="{folder.files}" as="file">
  <a href={file.publicUrl}>{file.name}</a>
</f:for>
<f:for each={folder.subFolders} as="subFolder">
  <f:if condition="{subFolder.files -> f:count()} > 0 OR {subFolder.subFolders -> f:count()} > 0">
    <div class="folder">{subFolder.name}</div>
    <f:render partial="FolderRecursive" arguments="{folder:subFolder}" />
  </f:if>
</f:for>
```

In your Template put something like this to display the folders:

```
<f:render partial="FolderRecursive" arguments="{folder:folder}" />
```